# How to group by first created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called Posts which are created by Users. Each post has a created_at attribute. I'd like to figure out how many users posted for the very first time on each date from a start-date to an end-date.

I'm trying to get a result like this:

```
1/1/2016: 15 posted for the first time
2/1/2016: 4 posted for the first time
3/1/2016: 0 posted for the first time
...
```

What's the best way to do this efficiently with ActiveRecord? :)

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: You can't just use created_at, it's a time stamp, you'll have to use a range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing that you should do is get the date of the post created_at

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def created_at_date 
    created_at.to_date
  end
  ...
end
```

now that you have that method in the post class you can now access it

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def get_first_post_created_at
    posts.first. created_at_date
  end
  ...
end
```

now the last thing that can do is our group by get_first_post_created_at

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.group_by_first_post_created
    User.all.group_by(&:get_first_post_created_at)
  end
  ...
end
```

I hope that this was able to help you :)